# What is algorithmic cost of adding, accessing or removing an element from an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

I have a web application that uses `ArrayList's` extensively to store and operate on data within itself. However,recently I understood that `HashMap's` may  have been a better choice. Could anyone tell me what exactly is the algorithmic cost(`Big O(n)`) of adding, accessing and removing an element from both and whether it is wise to go  into the code and change them for the sake of efficency?

Comment: HashMaps generally have O(1) insert, delete and lookups whereas ArrayLists have O(n) lookups and O(n) deletes. HashMaps also use a bit more memory and don't store the data in any sorted order. In general HashMaps are a good choice if you have to do a lot of lookups, but the trade-off may not be worth it if n is small.

Answer (score 8):

For ArrayList:

> The size, isEmpty, get, set, iterator, and listIterator operations run
>   in constant time. The add operation runs in amortized constant time,
>   that is, adding n elements requires O(n) time. All of the other
>   operations run in linear time (roughly speaking). The constant factor
>   is low compared to that for the LinkedList implementation.

From the documentation: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

For HashMap:

> This implementation provides constant-time performance for the basic
>   operations (get and put), assuming the hash function disperses the
>   elements properly among the buckets. Iteration over collection views
>   requires time proportional to the "capacity" of the HashMap instance
>   (the number of buckets) plus its size (the number of key-value
>   mappings). Thus, it's very important not to set the initial capacity
>   too high (or the load factor too low) if iteration performance is
>   important.

From the documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) has a discussion of the performance of the performance of these operations. As for `HashMap`, it will be `O(1)` for all three. This does assume, however, that your `hashCode` method is well-implemented, and is also `O(1)`.

Comment: ... assuming your `hashCode` is O(1).

Comment: Well, that's what I meant by `reasonable`.

Comment: Then why not say that? "Reasonable" is not very precise. Edit and you'll have my upvote.

Comment: Spoke too soon here - `hashCode` must also disperse elements properly (no/few collisions). In that way, perhaps "reasonable" was a better description. Sorry about that.

Comment: Indeed, being O(1) is not sufficient for a hashing function, `return 1;` would be a terrible, yet constant time, hashing function.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at http://www.coderfriendly.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/java_collections_v2.pdf

- O(1) to get/add
- O(n) for contains
- O(1) for next